# Difference between \w and \b regular expression meta characters

Tags: regex

Can anyone explain the difference between `\b` and `\w` regular expression metacharacters? It is my understanding that both these metacharacters are used for word boundaries. Apart from this, which meta character is efficient for multilingual content?

Comment: `\w` represents a word *character*, while `\b` represents a word *boundary between* a word character and a non-word character. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

The metacharacter `\b` is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a **"word boundary"**. This match is zero-length.

There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is
  a word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the
  last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the
  string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Simply put: `\b` allows you to perform a **"whole words only"** search using a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`. A **"word character"** is a character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not **"word characters"** are **"non-word characters"**.

In all flavors, the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` are word characters. These are also matched by the short-hand character class `\w`. Flavors showing **"ascii"** for word boundaries in the flavor comparison recognize only these as word characters.

`\w` stands for **"word character"**, usually `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits.

`\B` is the negated version of `\b`. `\B` matches at every position where `\b` does not. Effectively, `\B` matches at any position between two word characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters.

`\W` is short for `[^\w]`, the negated version of `\w`.

Answer (score 25):

`\w` matches a word character. `\b` is a zero-width match that matches a position character that has a word character on one side, and something that's not a word character on the other. (Examples of things that aren't word characters include whitespace, beginning and end of the string, etc.)

`\w` matches `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` in `"abc def"`
`\b` matches the (zero-width) position before `a`, after `c`, before `d`, and after `f` in `"abc def"`

See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html/

Comment: It's more correct to say that it's the boundary between a word character and not a word character because it also matches between a word character and the start or end of a string if that character is at the start/end of the string.

Comment: It's still not quite right.  `\b` a zero-width assertion; it doesn't match a *character*, it matches a *position*.

Answer (score 14):

@Mahender, you probably meant the difference between `\W` (instead of `\w`) and `\b`. If not, then I would agree with @BoltClock and @jwismar above. Otherwise continue reading.

`\W` would match any non-word character and so its easy to try to use it to match word boundaries. The problem is that it will not match the start or end of a line. `\b` is more suited for matching word boundaries as it will also match the start or end of a line. Roughly speaking (more experienced users can correct me here) `\b` can be thought of as `(\W|^|$)`. [Edit: as @Ωmega mentions below, `\b` is a zero-length match so `(\W|^|$)` is not strictly correct, but hopefully helps explain the diff]

Quick example: For the string `Hello World`, `.+\W` would match `Hello_` (with the space) but will not match `World`. `.+\b` would match both `Hello` and `World`.

Comment: I disagree at `\b` meaning the same as `(\W|^|$)`, since `(\W|^|$)` will include the non-word character inside the matching result. You can check this fact here => https://regexr.com/3qf98 .

Comment: `\b` for me, means the same as `(?<=\W|^|$)` when used before a pattern and `(?=\W|^|$)` when used after a pattern. You can check what I'm talking here => https://regexr.com/3qf9h . Just compare with the result of `\b` anchors right here => https://regexr.com/3qf9t

Answer (score 7):

```
\b <= this is a word boundary.
```

Matches at a position that is followed by a word character but not preceded by a word character, or that is preceded by a word character but not followed by a word character.

```
\w <= stands for "word character".
```

It always matches the ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_]

Is there anything specific you are trying to match?

Some useful regex websites for beginners or just to wet your appetite.

- http://www.regular-expressions.info
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml
- http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/php/37-tested-php-perl-and-javascript-regular-expressions
- http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/4862-master-javascript-regular-expressions.html

I found this to be a very useful book:

- [Mastering Regular Expressions by Jeffrey E.F. Friedl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)

Comment: This is a good answer, but it is useful to remember that `\w` is not always equivalent to the ASCII characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]` -- it will also match alphanumeric Unicode code points, and may match 8-bit ISO-Latin-1 characters if the locale is set appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

`\w` is *not* a word boundary, it matches any word character, including underscores: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. `\b` *is* a word boundary, that is, it matches the position between a word and a non-alphanumeric character: `\W` or `[^\w]`.

These implementations may vary from language to language though.