# Regular expression to validate username

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to validate usernames against these criteria:

1. Only contains *alphanumeric* characters,
   *underscore* and *dot*.
2. Underscore and dot can't be at the *end* or
   *start* of a username (e.g `_username` / `username_` / `.username` / `username.`).
3. Underscore and dot can't be *next to each other* (e.g `user_.name`).
4. Underscore or dot can't be used multiple times *in a row* (e.g `user__name` / `user..name`).
5. Number of characters must be between 8 to 20.

This is what I've done so far; it sounds it enforces all criteria rules *but the 5th rule*. I don't know how to add the 5th rule to this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: no , just one occurrence of underscore or dot is allowed each time

Comment: but a_b_c_d_e would be valid right?

Comment: yes , It is . I'm testing your Regular expression now , sounds working fine :)

Comment: Can there be more than one dot if separated by non-dots? i.e. `"A.B.C"` (same question for underscore?)

Comment: The syntax highlighting (if it can be called that) is non-broken in [this example](https://regexr.com/4ofm6) and actually provide some value. For this case, on Stack Overflow, the default is probably taken from the ASP.NET tag ("Code Language" (whatever that means - probably effectively, without hints, regular expressions will highlighted as C#)).

Answer (score 443, accepted):

```
^(?=.{8,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$
 └─────┬────┘└───┬──┘└─────┬─────┘└─────┬─────┘ └───┬───┘
       │         │         │            │           no _ or . at the end
       │         │         │            │
       │         │         │            allowed characters
       │         │         │
       │         │         no __ or _. or ._ or .. inside
       │         │
       │         no _ or . at the beginning
       │
       username is 8-20 characters long
```

---

If your browser raises an error due to lack of negative look-behind support, use the following alternative pattern:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9._]{8,20}$)(?!.*[_.]{2})[^_.].*[^_.]$
```

Comment: Nice one. But you may want to look into using free-spacing mode and embed your comments right in there with the code. +1

Comment: @ridgerunner - I believe this way it is easy to read and port to code.

Comment: @Ωmega can we use [\w\.] instead of [a-zA-Z0-9._]

Comment: @vigneshkumar - same meaning, but `[a-zA-Z0-9._]` is easy to read and understand

Comment: the `<` in `(?<![_.])$` causes a parsing error for me "invalid regular expression"

Comment: @JacksonLenhart - What regex engine and programming language you use? Please note this question was tagged with `asp.net` tag and while the answer is valid for most of other languages and engines, not all support negative lookahead and lookbehind zero-length assertions.

Comment: Ah yes, I was naive enough to think regex would be the same for all languages. I'm using javascript (es6), no additional regex engine

Comment: Please note that this regular expression causes an Angular app to crash on IOS devices, as well as on the Firefox browser.

Comment: For those who will use this in JS: this RegEx works great in Chrome. But it raises an error in Safari, Firefox, Edge, etc.

Comment: Firefox considers this regex to be a syntax error, and produces `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`.

Comment: Thanks @Ωmega It seems that also run in Flutter for android. I did not tested on ios.

Comment: First one didn't work with Safari but second one fixed it. Nice.

Answer (score 16):

I guess you'd have to use Lookahead expressions here. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Try

`^[a-zA-Z0-9](_(?!(\.|_))|\.(?!(_|\.))|[a-zA-Z0-9]){6,18}[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` an alphanumeric THEN (

`_(?!\.)` a _ not followed by a . OR

`\.(?!_)` a . not followed by a _ OR

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` an alphanumeric ) FOR

`{6,18}` minimum 6 to maximum 18 times THEN

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` an alphanumeric

(First character is alphanum, then 6 to 18 characters, last character is alphanum, 6+2=8, 18+2=20)

Comment: Try: `^[a-zA-Z0-9](_(?!(\.|_))|\.(?!(_|\.))|[a-zA-Z0-9]){6,18}[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

Comment: Yup, this one works. But the `(_|\.)` expression can be streamlined to just `[_.]`.

Comment: Nice, if somebody need such a RegEx for JS, this is the way. It works in all browsers unlike the most voted answer that's Chrome-only

Answer (score 15):

As much as I love regular expressions, I think there is a limit to what is readable.

So I would suggest

```
new Regex("^[a-z._]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(username) &&
!username.StartsWith(".") &&
!username.StartsWith("_") &&
!username.EndsWith(".") &&
!username.EndsWith("_") &&
!username.Contains("..") &&
!username.Contains("__") &&
!username.Contains("._") &&
!username.Contains("_.");
```

It's longer, but it won't need the maintainer to open expresso to understand.

Sure you can comment a long regex, but then whoever reads it has to rely on trust.

Comment: What is that in? C#?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, it's .NET to be specific. The `RegexOptions` Enum comes from the [`System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions?view=net-8.0)

Answer (score 9):

A slight modification to [Phillip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018245/regular-expression-to-validate-username/12018317#12018317) fixes the latest requirement of allowing a single instance of `.` or `_` between letters:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]([._](?![._])|[a-zA-Z0-9]){6,18}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Comment: This gives issue in character limit rule, with the given rule of `{6,18}` it accepts min 8 characters whereas it must be accepting 6, If I make it `{4,18}` then it will accept 6 characters whereas I have defined 4

Answer (score 4):

```
private static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    while (n-- != 0) {
        String userName = scan.nextLine();
        String regularExpression = "^[[A-Z]|[a-z]][[A-Z]|[a-z]|\\d|[_]]{7,29}$";
        if (userName.matches(regularExpression)) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 3):

```
^(?=.{4,20}$)(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:(?:\.|-|_)[a-zA-Z\d])*)+$
```

You can test the regex [here](https://regexr.com/4ofm6).

Comment: This is allowing underscore at the beginning and at the end, which is not wanted.

Comment: It also matches infinite length string that contains only underscore.

Comment: @Toto,  I fixed it.

Comment: Works fine, but allows `-` character, I made a little adjustment to it here: ``^(?=.{4,20}$)(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:[._][a-zA-Z\d])*)+$`` which fix it for me, thanks for the code @FrEqDe

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this question in [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72610374/php-regex-for-username-validation#comment128262834_72610374), and it seems not necessary to use that many lookarounds.
Following a bit shorter pattern with use of [`\w`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters/11874899#11874899) which is a [short](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for *word character* and commonly preset to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. To get rid of the underscore, [`[^\W_]`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#obnoxious) can be used to match `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

```
^[^\W_](?!.*?[._]{2})[\w.]{6,18}[^\W_]$
```

- `^[^\W_]` one letter or digit at the [start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `(?!.*?[._]{2})` negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to disallow `__` `._` `_.` `..`
  (for reduing steps on longer inputs, a [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301291/5527985) quantifier is used in `.*?`)
- `[\w.]{6,18}` 6 to 18 [characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)  that can be letters, digits, `_` and `.`
- `[^\W_]$` ending in another letter or digit

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GahDKa/1) (a further explanation is on the right side)

*Note*: `\w`, depending on environment/settings, can further contain Unicode letters and digits.

Answer (score 1):

`^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$`

^                # Start of the line

[a-z0-9_-]       # Match characters and symbols in the list, a-z, 0-9, underscore, hyphen

{3,15}           # Length at least 3 characters and maximum length of 15

$                # End of the line

Answer (score 0):

Err, sorry, I generated this from my own library and it uses the syntax valid for Dart/JavaScript/Java/Python, but anyway, here goes:

```
(?:^)(?:(?:[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKlMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]){1,1})(?!(?:(?:(?:(?:_\.){1,1}))|(?:(?:(?:__){1,1}))|(?:(?:(?:\.\.){1,1}))))(?:(?:(?:(?:[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKlMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789._]){1,1})(?!(?:(?:(?:(?:_\.){1,1}))|(?:(?:(?:__){1,1}))|(?:(?:(?:\.\.){1,1}))))){6,18})(?:(?:[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKlMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]){1,1})(?:$)
```

My library code:

```
var alphaNumeric = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "l", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
var allValidCharacters = new List.from(alphaNumeric);
allValidCharacters.addAll([".", "_"]);

var invalidSequence = (r) => r
  .eitherString("_.")
  .orString("__")
  .orString("..");

var regex = new RegExpBuilder()
  .start()
  .exactly(1).from(alphaNumeric).notBehind(invalidSequence)
  .min(6).max(18).like((r) => r.exactly(1).from(allValidCharacters).notBehind(invalidSequence))
  .exactly(1).from(alphaNumeric)
  .end()
  .getRegExp();
```

My library: https://github.com/thebinarysearchtree/RegExpBuilder

Comment: And "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" can't be expressed in a more compact form?

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the trick:

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"
    # Validate username with 5 constraints.
    ^                          # Anchor to start of string.
    # 1- only contains alphanumeric characters , underscore and dot.
    # 2- underscore and dot can't be at the end or start of username,
    # 3- underscore and dot can't come next to each other.
    # 4- each time just one occurrence of underscore or dot is valid.
    (?=[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$)
    # 5- number of characters must be between 8 to 20.
    [A-Za-z0-9_.]{8,20}        # Apply constraint 5.
    $                          # Anchor to end of string.
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
{
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = /^moe_(app|lab)[A-Za-z0-9]{3}$/;
const str = `moe_app_baa`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP is using ASP.NET. While that doesn't _preclude_ them from using JavaScript, it's ideal if answers that deviate from the OP's specified language explicitly say so, and provide justification for it.

Answer (score -3):

```
function isUserName(val){
    let regUser=/^[a-zA-Z0-9](_(?!(\.|_))|\.(?!(_|\.))|[a-zA-Z0-9]){6,18}[a-zA-Z0-9]$/;
    if(!regUser.test(val)){
      return 'Name can only use letters,numbers, minimum length is 8 characters';
    }
  }
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.