# Extract proper username from a string with regex in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract a username from a string that user has typed into input. The thing is that I don't want just simply validate username, but I want to show for user what will be the final username even if user types any non-allowed characters.

So for example if user types in something like `&%$User)(Nam-e` it will show `usernam-e`

there is similar question with answer [Regular expression to validate username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018245/regular-expression-to-validate-username), but somehow it gives me an error of `Invalid group` on  node.js when I try to use it with a `match` or `exec` functions.

Anyway, most of the examples online only validates the username against regex, but not actually provides the outcome of the appropriate username.

Rules are following:

1. Only contains alphanumeric characters, underscore, dash and dot.
2. Underscore, dash and dot can't be at the end or start of a username
   (e.g `_username` / `username_`).
3. Underscore, dash and dot can't be next to each other (e.g
   `user_-.name`).
4. Underscore, dash or dot can't be used multiple times in a row (e.g
   `user__name`).

So far I was only capable to do something similar with using `replace` function number of times

```
value.replace(/[^\w-]*/g,'').replace(/^[^a-z]*/,'').replace(/-{2,}/g,'-').replace(/_{2,}/g,'_');
```

But this doesn't look like an efficient code, especially that I would actually need to add even more `replace` functions to extract appropriate username.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumes that you want the name displayed in lower-case, as in your example:

```
function user( n ) {
    var name = n.replace( /^[^a-z]+|[^a-z\d_\-.]|[_\-.](?![a-z\d])/gi, '' );    
    if ( n != name ) {
        console.log( 'Username invalid' );
    }
    return name.toLowerCase(); 
}

user('&%$User)(Nam-e');    // Username invalid, usernam-e                                             
user('_Giedrius_one_');    // Username invalid, giedrius_one                                                                                                 
user('Giedrius--one');     // Username invalid, giedrius-one                                            
user('Giedrius-one');      // giedrius-one  
user('/.bob_/');           // Username invalid, bob
```

Comment: Found one mistake, if you type more than one of the allowed special character at the beginning, string will start with special character. .-username => -username . 
A slightly updated version of regex - /[^a-z\d_\-.]|^[_\-.]+|[_\-.](?=[_\-.])|[_\-.]$/gi

Comment: After playing around found more mistakes, like `\.bob_\ ` returning `.bob_` Turns out that order is quite important. This one is the final one that I came up with and  found no mistakes yet `/^[^a-z]+|[^\w-.]|[_\-.](?=[^a-z0-9])|[^a-z\d]$/gi` Thanks a lot for showing the right path.

Comment: @Giedrius. Realised only one regex required and updated answer. Apologies for not testing more - it was late.