# How to validate edit text in android for special characters?

Tags: java, android, validation

There are so many questions and answers regarding this topic,but my problem is I have edit text in my app,there I need to enter a name,so I need to validate my edit text,to avoid **spaces** and **special characters** as the only name,and edit text **can't be empty** also.How can I do that without textwatcher.

Comment: Be specific, u need to validate on each keystroke or after a button click?

Comment: When I click the add button to add Name,I need to show the error message whenever the field is empty or the field is only with special characters

Comment: if(edittext1.matches("")){
                    e2.setError("Invalid Address");
                }   add on xml file->android:inputType="textFilter"

Comment: 1. What are special characters?   2. what you try?   3. You can show keyboard without group of characters/numbers  4. regular expression, like this: ^(?=.{8,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018245/regular-expression-to-validate-username

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple regular expression

```
public boolean isValidWord(String word) {

    return word.matches("[A-Za-z][^.]*");
}
```

if return value is true then your input dont have a special char or spaces.. if false it may have special char or spaces.. simple and elegant..

Just call the method with the string paramater before add your name..

Comment: For all other characters,this answer is good,but for the `.` (fullstop symbol) your code is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use input filter to filter out special characters and white space

```
 edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            String regex = "a-z~@#$%^&*:;<>.,/}{+";
            if(!dest.toString().contains(" ")||!dest.toString().matches("[" + regex + "]+")){
            return null;
            }
        }

    } });
```

I hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

```
String username=edittext1.getText().toString();
if(username.matches("")) {
     edittext1.setError("Invalid ");
}
```

add on xml file

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

may be it will help

Answer (score -1):

edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter() {

```
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        String regex = "a-z~@#$%^&*:;<>.,/}{+";
        if(!dest.toString().contains(" ")||!dest.toString().matches("[" + regex + "]+")){
        return null;
        }
    }

} });
```