# Regular expression to validate a specific pattern

Tags: regex, validation

I'm trying to create a regular expression with the below restrictions

1. Allow any character '\w\W\s' (e.g rand123#!#@adfads)
2. Disallow only numbers (e.g 12312312)
3. Disallow only non alphanumeric characters (e.g !@#$$#%#^%$^%)
4. Number of characters must be between 3 to 60

Following along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018245/regular-expression-to-validate-username), but could not get it work.

```
^(?=.{3,60}$)(?![\W_]*$)(?![0-9]*$)[\w\W\s]+$
```

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Try [`^(?![\w\W]*[\W_]{2})(?![\w\W]*[0-9]{2})[\w\W]{3,60}$`](https://regex101.com/r/dD2pR7/1).

Comment: Or (after your edit) [`^(?![\W_]+$)(?![0-9]+$)[\w\W]{3,60}$`](https://regex101.com/r/dD2pR7/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\W` matches `\s`, so `'\w\W\s'` can be reduced to `[\w\W]`.

You may use 2 negative lookaheads anchored at the start to impose two "disallow-only" conditions like this:

```
^(?![\W_]+$)(?![0-9]+$)[\w\W]{3,60}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD2pR7/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![\W_]+$)` - the string cannot consist of non-alphanumeric chars
- `(?![0-9]+$)` - the string cannot consist of digits only
- `[\w\W]{3,60}` - 3 to 60 any characters
- `$` - end of string.