# Specific String validation using regex

Tags: java, regex, validation, constraints

I have been told to use regex instead of `isUpperCase()`, `isLowerCase()`, etc... but I have no clue on how use regex.

This is what I need to check:

```
length min = 8 characters
length max = 20 characters
must contain at least one lower case character (a-z)
must contain at least one upper case character (A-Z)
must contain at least one number (0-9)
must contain at least one special character
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: He did the effort and found Stackoverflow xD

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018245/regular-expression-to-validate-username

Comment: Is this your homework?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn, how to use regex, I recommend the following

- read your lecture notes
- read a Java book (especially the chapters about "Pattern" and "regular expressions")
- read the Java documentation, e.g. about [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

Regex of upper case is `[A-Z]` and for lower case is `[a-z]`
Both tests for at at least ONE occurence of given char group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from Javascript.  Java will be similar:

```
var password = '0Aa!.......'
const regexp = /[0-9]?[a-z]?[A-Z]?[^0-9A-Za-z]?/;
var isValid = (password.length >= 8 && password.length <= 20) && regexp.test(password);
```

This tests that there are at least one number, then one capital, then one lowercase, then one that isn't a number or letter.  It demonstrates the concept, not the exact solution.

I agree with others that you should dig in to the reading more.  Regular expressions and Java are well documented.

Comment: Wouldn't this match "AAAAAAAA"? Your example requires a very specific order.  I don't think this is possible without lookaheads

Comment: You are correct, quackenator.  I was trying to demonstrate how regexes are used, not what the exact solution is.  The question was getting down-voted, but I wanted to give the author a starting point to do more reading.  That's why I didn't do the answer in Java (which he was looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I haven't tested this in Java, but this does work with the pcre engine.

```
^(?=.{8,20}$)(?=[^A-Z]*?[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*?[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*?[0-9])(?=[^!@#$%^&*]*?[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]+$
```

Broken down:

```
    ^(?=.{8,20}$)               //this matches 8 to 20 characters, inclusive (positive lookahead)
    (?=[^A-Z]*?[A-Z])           //this matches if one uppercase letter is present (positive lookahead)
    (?=[^a-z]*?[a-z])           //this matches if one lowercase letter is present (positive lookahead)
    (?=[^0-9]*?[0-9])           //this matches if one digit is present (positive lookahead)
    (?=[^!@#$%^&*]*?[!@#$%^&*]) //this matches if one special character is present (positive lookahead)
    [a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]+$       //this matches if the enclosed characters are present
```

This may be a bit over the top for what you want but I have tested it here:
https://regex101.com/r/P0J4X8/1

Also, the lazy evaluators may be unnecessary in the lookaheads

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to test this in Java.
May I ask you how the regex would become with this additional check ("must NOT contain one or more identical consecutive characters")?

Comment: I've tried the following string: ".getInfo(0)$%@;" but it didn't work.

Comment: I would look into negative lookaheads, capturing groups, and repeating a capturing group.