# How to express the following regex expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, joi

I am poor with Regular expressions, following is the requirement.
I will be using this with Joi validators.

ID :

- Should be alphanumeric
- Cannot have any special characters except dash and underscore (- and _)
- Cannot have - or _ consecutively (Example: this-id is ok but this--id is not.

Name:

- Should be alphanumeric
- Cannot have any special characters except dash and underscore (- and _), but space is allowed.
- Cannot have - or _ consecutively (Example: this-id is ok but this--id is not.

Comment: You forgot to show your attempted regex

Comment: Have you looked at this: [Regular expression to validate username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018245/regular-expression-to-validate-username)

Comment: You can experiment with regular expressions on websites like https://regex101.com/. Its a good way to learn how to match specific text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex for ID:

```
^[-_]?(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+[-_]?)+$
```

- `[-_]?` allows underscore or hyphen to appear at the start too
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` matches one or more alphanumeric characters
- `[-_]?` allows zero or one hyphen or underscore
- Whole pattern is surrounded within a non capturing group and a `+` to indicate that it may repeat one or more times

Thus is ensures that no 2 hyphens or underscores appear in succession

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WTNoEE/1)

Regex for Name:

```
^[-_]?(?:[A-Za-z0-9 ]+[-_]?)+$
```

EDIT: Improvement to fix underscore or hyphen appearing at the start too. Thanks to @ErikBrodyDreyer for the catch! :)

Comment: That won't match the case where the ID begins with a hyphen or underscore, if that case needs to be accepted too.

Comment: @ErikBrodyDreyer good point, missed that. Can be fixed by adding `[-_]?` at the start, outside the non-capturing group

Answer (score 0):

([a-zA-Z0-9]*(_)?(?!\2)(\-)?(?!\3))+

this will do the work
it will match also -_ prefix

Answer (score 0):

**ID :**    `^(?!.*([_-])\1)[\w-]+$`

**Name :**  `^(?!.*([_-])\1)[\w -]+$`

A `\w` is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so the underscore is included.

The `(?!.*([_-])\1)` is a negative lookahead that won't allow a double dash or double underscore after the start of the string `^`.