# How to convert a regex pattern that uses Lookahead?

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds

I'm having trouble converting this regex to something Golang supports. Could I get some help? It's originally from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018245/regular-expression-to-validate-username).

```
^(?=.{1,24}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$
```

Here's the criteria:

> 1. Only contains *alphanumeric* characters,
>      *underscore* and *dot*.
> 2. Underscore and dot can't be at the *end* or
>      *start* of a username (e.g `_username` / `username_` / `.username` / `username.`).
> 3. Underscore and dot can't be *next to each other* (e.g `user_.name`).
> 4. Underscore or dot can't be used multiple times *in a row* (e.g `user__name` / `user..name`).

Comment: BTW, I forgot a `+` at the end. Please use the updated pattern; otherwise, it will allow only one dot or underscore.

Comment: Generally speaking, the best way to solve problems with regular expressions is not to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Go, so perhaps someone could come up with a better solution.
Here are the two options I found:

### 1. Write a regex that covers everything *except the length restriction*

You can use something like this:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$
```

[**Regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ZVlDih/3).

And you can use [`len`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/len-go) to check for the string length. Here's a full example:

```
func main() { 
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$`)
    var str = `username
user_name
user.name
user.name_123
username$$$
_username
username_
user_.name
user._name
user__name
user..name
VeryLongUserNameThatExceedsTheLimit
`
    for i, match := range re.FindAllString(str, -1) {
        if len(match) <= 24 {fmt.Println(match, "found at index", i)}
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
username found at index 0
user_name found at index 1
user.name found at index 2
user.name_123 found at index 3
```

[**Test it online**](https://rextester.com/QCTJK27211).

---

### 2. Use a third-party engine

I found [this .NET-based engine](https://github.com/dlclark/regexp2) which should support Lookarounds. If the previous solution doesn't work for you, you may look into this. Note that the author of that engine recommends using the built-in engine whenever possible:

> You'll likely be better off with the RE2 engine from the `regexp`
>   package and should only use this if you need to write very complex
>   patterns or require compatibility with .NET.