# Is there a way to stop a discord.py bot from mentioning roles?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot with discord.py, and I have a say command, but you can make the bot mention any role. I have already stopped it from mentioning @everyone and @here, but I can't figure out how to stop it from mentioning roles. Here's the code

```
async def say(ctx, *, message=None):
message = message or "You have to type a message"
message_components = message.split()
if "@everyone" in message_components or "@here" in message_components:
    await ctx.send("You can not ping everyone")
    return

await ctx.message.delete()
await ctx.send(message)
```

Comment: Do you have an idea of where to begin?

Comment: Is the issue resolved? If so, please mark any of the answers as accepted. @temp84323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `message.role_mentions`

```py
mentions = message.role_mentions

my_role = ctx.guild.get_role(some_id)

if my_role in mentions:
    await ctx.send("You can't mention that role")
```

If you have multiple roles

```py
my_roles = [] # a list of `discord.Role` objects

mentions = message.role_mentions

if any(role in mentions for role in my_roles):
    await ctx.send("You can't mention that role")
```

Also a better way of checking if `@everyone` and `@here` is mentioned in the message content itself, you can use the `message.mention_everyone` attribute

```py
if message.mention_everyone:
    await ctx.send("You can't mention everyone")
```

Reference

- [`Message.role_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.role_mentions)
- [`Message.mention_everyone`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Message.mention_everyone)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexes. Assuming only uppercase/lowercase alphanumeric characters are allowed for a valid username/role:

```
import re
user_regex = r"@[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
message = "I'm tagging @you and @you2 in this message!"
match = re.findall(user_regex, message)
if match:
    await ctx.send("You can not ping everyone")
    return
```

Of-course, you can use a well-sophisticated [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018245/regular-expression-to-validate-username) for your username, if you desire. Or you can figure out the regex for role as per your requirements and try matching accordingly.

Comment: actually role mentions don't look like this `@role` (only `everyone` and `here`), but like this `<@&role_id>`