# Remove all characters after a certain match

Tags: regex

I am using Notepad++ to remove some unwanted strings from the end of a pattern and this for the life of me has got me.

I have the following sets of strings:

```
myApp.ComboPlaceHolderLabel,
myApp.GridTitleLabel);
myApp.SummaryLabel + '</b></div>');
myApp.NoneLabel + ')') + '</label></div>';
```

I would like to leave just `myApp.[variable]` and get rid of, e.g. `,`, `);`, `+ '...'`, etc.

Using Notepad++, I can match the strings themselves using `^myApp.[a-zA-Z0-9].*?\b` (it's a bit messy, but it works for what I need).

But in reality, I need *negate* that regex, to match everything at the end, so I can replace it with a blank.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to go for negation. Just put your regex within  capturing groups and add an extra `.*$` at the last. `$` matches the end of a line. All the matched characters(*whole line*) are replaced by the characters which are present inside the first captured group. `.`
matches any character, so you need to escape the dot to match a literal dot.

```
^(myApp\.[a-zA-Z0-9].*?\b).*$
```

Replacement string:

```
\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oY5nA8/7)

**OR**

Match only the following characters and then replace it with an empty string.

```
\b[,); +]+.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oY5nA8/9)

Answer (score 3):

I think this works equally as well:

```
^(myApp.\w+).*$
```

Replacement string:

```
\1
```

---

From [difference between \w and \b regular expression meta characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters):

- `\w` stands for "word character", usually `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits.

Answer (score 2):

```
(^.*?\.[a-zA-Z]+)(.*)$
```

Use this.Replace by

`$1`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lU7jH1/5

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you :) now to try to make sense of it!

Comment: This matches any other strings which isn't starts with `myApp`