# How can I split string by same sequence of symbols using REGEX?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, split

I have string "'a'a'a'a'b'c'c'a'a'd'e'e'e'e"
and I need create an array of strings in this mode:

```
["'a'a'a'a'", "b'", "c'c'", "a'a'" ,"d'", "e'e'e'e"]
```

How can I get it with regex?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: I try it in Scala/Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match them with

```
(?:^')?(.')\1*(?:.$)?
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hX0aX7/4)

The regex matches optional `'` at the beginning with `(?:^')?`, then matches and captures any symbol other than a newline followed by a `'` (with `(.')`), followed by itself any number of times (with `\1*`) and then followed by an optional any symbol but  a newline at the end of the string (with `(?:.$)?`).

Output:

```
'a'a'a'a'
b'
c'c'
a'a'
d'
e'e'e'e
```

Comment: See my [previous PHP demo](https://ideone.com/rpHGnq) with incorrect placing of apostrophes, and [the current one](https://ideone.com/4S8BnL).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of splitting you can use a match using this regex:

```
(('[^']+)\2*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tO8uA2/1)

This will match a single quote followed by 1 or more non-single-quote character and group it. Later a back-reference can be used to match 0 or more occurrences of captured string.

Answer (score 0):

[This regex uses lookarounds](https://regex101.com/r/dN5nA8/1). In the lookbehind it captures and looks ahead.

```
(?<=(\w)'(?!\1))
```

Matches right after `'` if between different characters and left is a [word character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters/11874899#11874899).