# Capturing the previous three and next three words from a sentence based on searched word

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to retrieve the previous three and next three words of the searched word from a string in java.
For example:

```
 I have a string:
 A quick brown cat jumped over the lazy dog.
 A quick brown monkey move over the lazy dog.
 A quick brown monkey jumped over the lazy dog.
```

And a searched word is : **jumped**

I want the output as:

```
quick brown cat jumped over the lazy 
quick brown monkey jumped over the lazy
```

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far? Show some effort.

Comment: nop this is not a homework. Actually i am able to search a word from file and returned those lines that contained that word. And this is the additional requirement from my work which i am trying hard to tackle

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's homework or home work -- this is a lazy question where you show no evidence of prior effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use the combination of `\S` and `\s` to match bot space and non-space characters.

```
Pattern.compile("(?:\\S+\\s+){3}" + search_word + "(?:\\s+\\S+){3}");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fE3eW1/1)

Comment: Does `\w` not work in Java's `Pattern`? Or are `\S` and `\s` regex patterns I haven't heard of? I thought `\s` was whitespace.

Comment: @Arc676 no, it should work.. `\s` for all the spaces `\S` for all the non-spaces (inverse of `\s`)..

Comment: Advantages over using `\b`? (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters))

Comment: But if i search 'lazy' it does nothing. Can you make it in a dynamic way that i put any word and it return previous 3 and next 3 words?

Comment: .... speaking of lazy .... what's wrong with borrowing the concept and trying to fix it yourself? `</rolls_eyes>`

Answer (score -1):

This code will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.add("A quick brown cat jumped over the lazy dog.");
        l1.add("A quick brown monkey move over the lazy dog..");
        l1.add("A quick brown monkey jumped over the lazy dog.");

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s((\\w+\\s){3}jumped\\s(\\w+\\s){3})");
        for (String s : l1) {
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(1));
            }
        }

    }
```

O/P :

```
quick brown cat jumped over the lazy 
quick brown monkey jumped over the lazy
```