# Regex word boundary (backspace) test case

Tags: javascript, regex, unit-testing, keyboard-events

I want to test this condition if the key event is backspace or not:

```
  if (key.match(/[\b]/)) {
    return true;
  }
```

where `key` is coming from keystroke. (like `'a', '6' , '.'` etc)
What should be the value of `key` for `if` condition to return `true`?

I tried `key` as `'.'` since it is a word boundary (But only with a word, sadly). What should be the key to show `backspace <-`.

Comment: you mean this ? `key.match(/[\w.]/)`

Comment: No, It will match any word (word character). I want to match a word boundary. They are different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters

Comment: You can't detect a word boundary without at least two characters to compare. Testing `\b` against a character always is *true*. Against a space = false. Also, your regex tests to see if a backspace character is present, not a word boundary. Check [here at regex1010](https://regex101.com/r/zI1rV5/1) - explanation in the right pane.

Comment: `[\b]` matches a backspace character since `\b` is inside a character class. To match a word boundary, use `/\b/`. @ClasG: You can return true with just 1 character - but it must be a word character. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lB3wN0/1)

Comment: I thought backspace is also a word boundary. Actually I needed to test the key event for backspace since in FF I can't delete typed chars. Updated the question and thanks for correcting me. @ClasG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[\b]` matches a backspace character since `\b` is inside a character class. To match a word boundary, use `/\b/` (where `\b` is ***not*** inside a character class):

```js
var key = "a";
if (/\b/.test(key)) { // Or, perhaps, for better portability, /[\x08]/.test(key)
    alert(true);
}
```

If you plan to match all non-word characters you just need `\W`, not `\b`. The *word boundary* `\b` matches a position between `^` and `\w` or `\w` and `$`, or `\W` and `\w` or `\w` and `\W` (where `\w` stands for a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `\W` stands for any other character not inside these ranges). Also, if you need to match a 1-char string, do not forget anchors: `/^\W$/`.

**UPDATE**

To test a backspace key, you can use

```js
var key = "\x08";
if (/[\b]/.test(key)) {
 alert(true);
}
```

Comment: I needed to match the backspace. Updated the question. Upvoted answer for correcting me for mistaking word boundary and backspace. Thought backspace is also a word boundary.

Comment: I guess the answer is just what you need then :) Or do you want to delete your post now?

Comment: No. The code is working. When it is backspace it is returning true. I want to mock the behavior. Means, what value should I manually add to variable `key` so that it will return true? if it's `.` , `a` etc it will return false. I am unit-testing the function.

Comment: I guess `/[\b]/.test("\x08")`

Comment: That's a good way to go. I suppose it have good browser support. (Phones also have the same unicodes, right?)

Comment: That is a good point: maybe you should use `/[\x08]/.test(key)` for better portability. I do not remember right now where a problem can arise, but using the `\x` notation may be helpful in general.