# preg_replace_callback: including curly braces in a pattern: { is captured, } isn't

Tags: php, regex, unicode, word-boundary, named-captures

I have this function, which makes use of preg_replace_callback to split a sentence into "chains" of blocks belonging to different categories (alphabetic, han characters, everything else).

The function is trying to also include the characters  **'** ,  **{** ,  and **}** as "alphabetic"

```
function String_SplitSentence($string)
{
 $res = array();

 preg_replace_callback("~\b(?<han>\p{Han}+)\b|\b(?<alpha>[a-zA-Z0-9{}']+)\b|(?<other>[^\p{Han}A-Za-z0-9\s]+)~su",
 function($m) use (&$res) 
 {
 if (!empty($m["han"])) 
 {
  $t = array("type" => "han", "text" => $m["han"]);
  array_push($res,$t);
 }
 else if (!empty($m["alpha"])) 
 {
  $t = array("type" => "alpha", "text" => $m["alpha"]);
  array_push($res, $t);
 }
 else  if (!empty($m["other"])) 
 {
  $t = array("type" => "other", "text" => $m["other"]);
  array_push($res, $t);
 }
 },
 $string);

 return $res;
}
```

However, something seems to be wrong with the curly braces.

```
print_r(String_SplitSentence("Many cats{1}, several rats{2}"));
```

As can be seen in the output, the function treats { as an alphabetic character, as indicated, but stops at } and treats it as "other" instead.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => alpha
            [text] => Many
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => alpha
            [text] => cats{1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => other
            [text] => },
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => alpha
            [text] => several
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => alpha
            [text] => rats{2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [type] => other
            [text] => }
        )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. Running your code in 3v4l reveals that your regex [**works as expected**](https://3v4l.org/6AGEg).

Comment: Character class typo? `a-zA-Z0-9}'`?  You have `}` in your alpha character class but not `{`.  Is that the monkeywrench?  you have no `.` in your pattern, so the `s` flag is needless.  What php version are you running on?  What is your expected result.

Comment: sorry everyone, I pasted the code includig only } as I was testing it. Now I added back both { and } in the regex. Maybe I should also specify: php 7.0

Comment: My expected result would be  [1] => Array([type] => alpha[text] => cats{1})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be completely sure, because your sample input doesn't represent any Chinese characters and I don't know what kind of fringe cases you may be trying to process, but this is how I would write the pattern:

```
~(?<han>\p{Han}+)|(?<alpha>[a-z\d{}']+)|(?<other>\S+)~ui
```

The trouble with `\b` is that it is looking for `\w` characters.  `\w` represents uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores.  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874899/2943403

Also your pattern doesn't include any `.`s so you can remove the `s` pattern modifier.

---

Also your function call seems to be abusing `preg_replace_callback()`.  I mean, you aren't actually replacing anything, so it is an inappropriate call.  Perhaps you could consider this rewrite:

```
function String_SplitSentence($string){
    if(!preg_match_all("~(?<han>\p{Han}+)|(?<alpha>[a-z\d{}']+)|(?<other>\S+)~ui",$string,$out)){
        return [];  // or $string or false
    }else{
        foreach($out as $group_key=>$group){
            if(!is_numeric($group_key)){  // disregard the indexed groups (which are unavoidably generated)
                foreach($group as $i=>$v){
                    if(strlen($v)){  // only store the value in the subarray that has a string length
                        $res[$i]=['type'=>$group_key,'text'=>$v];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ksort($res);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

A demonstration about your pattern:  https://regex101.com/r/6EUaSM/1

\b after your character class was fouling it all up.  `}` is not included in the `\w` class.  Regex wants to do a good job for you -- it captured "greedily" until it couldn't anymore.  The `}` was getting left out because of the word boundary.

Comment: @resle If you have any fringe cases that my pattern fails on, please supply the input string and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work so far. Can you explain, specifically, why "{" was captured but } wasn't?

Comment: Added a bit more for you

Comment: Thanks, understood. Works flawlessly also with Chinese characters.  You might want to add ksort($res) as otherwise the order of returned "blocks" doesn't follow the original sentence ordering.

Comment: Fixed the keys.  Good advice.