# Capitalize after period in javascript live, while writing in the input field

Tags: javascript

How to capitalize first letter after period?
For example, If entering name in textbox like `j.daniel pigott` or `j. daniel pigott` it should reflect as `J.Daniel Pigott` and remove space. I can capitalize first letter while typing, how to change letter to uppercase after period from below code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxName" runat="server" CssClass="tbxCandidateInfo" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>

    $('#tbxName').keyup(function (event) {
        var arrWord = $(this).val().split(' ');
        var result = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < arrWord.length; i++) {
            result += arrWord[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + arrWord[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
            if (i < arrWord.length - 1) {
                result += ' ';
            }
        }
        $(this).val(result);
    });

    1) While user entering his name (any name) it should *Capitalize* first letter
    2) If user entering his name along with initial then *Capitalize* the word after period.
3) Uppercase for entire words not allowed.
These changes should happen while entering this name field ***onkeyup*** event
```

Comment: Seems you WANT to capitalize ALL initial letters. Why is after a full stop relevant? You would for example (wrongly) capitalize many Dutch/German names like "R. van Winkel" - Also I do not want to be `M.Plungjan`I want to be `M. Plungjan` with a space

Comment: Do you need this to happen when you type or after?

Comment: Yes this should happen while typing

Comment: btw, from the [sight of typography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11332/should-there-be-a-space-between-name-initials), the space after the dot is necessary.

Comment: what should happens with some name parts, like `'van Helsing'`?

Comment: And what happens if I enter two spaces after the dot?

Comment: @0143.NetUser do not forget to accept an answer, if there is a solution which helped you

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is this:

```js
console.log('example:')
console.log(
    "j. delan pegot".replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase()).replace('. ', '.')
);

const stringCapitalize = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase()).replace('. ', '.')
}

const onChange = (evt) => {
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  input.value = stringCapitalize(input.value);
}
```

```html
<Label>Write something: </Label><input id="input" onkeyup="onChange()" />
```

You need to attach an `onkeyup` function which will do what I described above. Try the input in the demo.

**Edit:**
For understanding the regex please refer to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters
```

Comment: While I agree with this answer, I recommend to add an explanation for the regex.

Comment: Thank you very much Bogdan, It should not accept all letter in uppercase only first letter

Comment: @Martijn added a reference

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to do it with CSS --

```
#tbxName {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

See the reference here -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

It'll work as you're typing, too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function upperCase(){
var a = document.getElementById('input');
var val = a.value;
uppCase = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1)
a.value = uppCase;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" onkeyup="upperCase()" />
```