# stringr::str_extract all elements of a list R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I'm trying to get all the "banana + word" ocurrences of a given object, but the str_extract returns only the first occurence. My code:

```
all_terms <- c("banana word2 word3 word4 banana split word2 word3 word4",
               "x y z",
               "banana ice cream")

banana_terms <- all_terms %>% 
  str_extract("banana.+") %>% 
  word(1,2)


banana_terms
Out: [1] "banana word2" NA             "banana ice"
```

What I wanted:

```
Out: [1] "banana word2" "banana split", "banana ice"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str_extract_all` and `\\w+` to get the word after banana (and banana).

```r
all_terms %>% 
  str_extract_all("banana.\\w+") %>% 
  unlist()

# [1] "banana word2" "banana split" "banana ice"
```

Without unlist, you get a list:

```r
str_extract_all(all_terms, "banana.\\w+")

[[1]]
[1] "banana word2" "banana split"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "banana ice"
```

Comment: It works! Can you explain me what is the \\w ? Is it word? I could not find in my cheat sheet (https://spannbaueradam.shinyapps.io/r_regex_tester/)

Comment: Basically yes, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters) maybe for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `str_extract`, you need to make sure each "banana word" is an individual element in a vector.

`str_split` is used to split every "empty space" + "banana" pattern (`" (?=banana)"`) into individual element. Then use the regex (`banana.\\w+`) provided by @Maël in `str_extract`.

Finally, remove `NA` in the vector.

```
library(stringr)

all_banana <- str_extract(str_split(all_terms, " (?=banana)", simplify = T), "banana.\\w+")
all_banana <- all_banana[!is.na(all_banana)]

all_banana
[1] "banana word2" "banana ice"   "banana split"
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `regmatches/gregexpr`

```
unlist(regmatches(all_terms, gregexpr("banana\\s+\\S+", all_terms)))
[1] "banana word2" "banana split" "banana ice"
```