# Regex replace all occurences of a word unless its the last word

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace all occurrences of a word unless the word is at the end of the sentence, for example:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

If I am removing the word dog, the above sentence should remain the same,

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

but if the sentence was:

```
The dog was lazy
```

dog would be removed from the sentence and would have the following result;

```
The was lazy
```

I am not well versed with regex I tried something like this;

```
(dog)(?=(dog))
```

Apparently this is wrong, because it does not remove any.

Comment: You probably mean `/\bdog\b(?!$)/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/\bdog\b(?!$)/g
```

If you need to account end of any line:

```
/\bdog\b(?!$)/gm
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `dog` - a word `dog`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if  there is end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QRDhUP/1).

*Note*: to also remove initial whitespace, add `\s*`: `\s*\bdog\b(?!$)`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a word and [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) *non-word characters* if there is another word ahead:

```
\bdog\W+\b
```

- `\b` matches a *word boundary* [...more about `\b` and `\w`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters/11874899#11874899)
- Upper `\W` is the negation of `\w` which is a short for *word character*

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VJb4Mk/1) (I used [`[^\w\n]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) instead `\W` for not skipping lines in multiline-demo)