# How to match decimal numbers with no leading zeros?

Tags: java, regex

I'm dealing with a regex in Java that should capture all occurrences of decimal numbers with no leading zeros.

Example:

> The cat is .75 high but the dog id 3.67 high instead. All animals
> aren't higher that .87.

I expect to capture only **.75** and **.87** as they are decimals with whatever numbers of digits, but without the leading zero. I should not capture **3.67** instead.

I tried capturing it with word boundaries on both sides:

```
\b\.\d+\b
```

But the word boundary on the left side of this doesn't work well. Without the word boundary, it matches **3.67** too.

What would be the correct regex syntax to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Well I could have begin of line or a special control char like a Tab..so not only spaces.

Comment: 3.67 *is* a decimal number with no leading zeroes.  Did you mean no leading _digits_?

Comment: Alternately, does "decimal number" mean a number that is between 0 and 1?  Also, should negative numbers be allowed?

Answer (score 3):

You want to match the opposite of `\b` at the start of the pattern. For this, there is [uppercase `\B`, which matches where `\b` doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874899/5527985).

Basically, you're looking for a decimal point that is *not* at a word boundary (because there would be a word boundary between the decimal point and any other numbers), followed by numbers, followed by a word boundary.

> \B matches at every position where \b does not. Effectively, \B matches at any position between two word characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters.

```
\B\.\d+\b
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GioMy5/1)

Comment: Gosh well, yes, I'm testing and actually I think so, but if I want to have whole word only both on left and right side, why on right side \b works and it doesn't on left side if it is actually same condition ? (E.g.: have a space or an end of line) ?

Comment: @StefanoFalconetti On the right side there is a digit, which belongs to word-characters thus the word boundary after `\d+` matches, if there is not another word character right to it. `\B` would match between two word characters or two non-word characters like you want it on the left side where there is a dot and you don't want a digit (word-character) before it.