# R Extract Partial String from Specific Rows

Tags: r, apply, substr

I have a dataframe 'df1' with a string column 'Field_notes' of various information that looks like this:

| Alt_ID | Field_notes |
| --- | --- |
|  | JMs # 04J0342 |
|  | JMs # 04J0343 |
|  | JMs # 04J0344 |
|  | # broken leg |
|  | 54.2 |
|  | JMs # 04J0345 |

I would like to extract parts of the strings from the "Field_notes" column for specific rows only to the "Alt_ID" column. In this case, I'd like to subset rows 1,2,3,6 so that the alphanumeric combination after "JMs # " is moved to the "Alt_ID" column, so the result looks like:

| Alt_ID | Field_notes |
| --- | --- |
| 04J0342 | JMs # 04J0342 |
| 04J0343 | JMs # 04J0343 |
| 04J0344 | JMs # 04J0344 |
|  | # broken leg |
|  | 54.2 |
| 04J0345 | JMs # 04J0345 |

The tricky part is that there are so many combinations of information in Field_notes that I probably can't rely on character patterns and instead have to rely on specifying row names/numbers. In this case, I don't want to extract anything from '# broken leg'.

Comment: Try `Alt_ID <- sub('.*#\\s+', '', df1$Field_notes)`.

Comment: It worked for the rows of interest, but also grabbed information from all other rows and placed it in Alt_ID, so not the answer I was hoping for. However, maybe I can refine your answer. Can you explain what this section means: '.*#\\s+'?

Comment: If you can't rely on patterns how would you like to identify which rows you want to pick out to get the substrings? And once you get those rows, without a standard pattern how would you know what substrings to extract?

Answer (score 2):

Update:

Here is another approach: Now you don't rely on `#` but now you rely on count of characters:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Alt_ID = ifelse(nchar(Field_notes)==13,  str_extract(Field_notes,  '\\b\\w+$'), ""), .before=1)
```

```
  Alt_ID   Field_notes
1 04J0342 JMs # 04J0342
2 04J0343 JMs # 04J0343
3 04J0344 JMs # 04J0344
4            broken leg
5                  54.2
6 04J0345 JMs # 04J0345
```

First answer:

A combination of regex `'\\b\\w+$'` and `stringr` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Alt_ID= str_extract(Field_notes,  '\\b\\w+$')) %>% 
  mutate(Alt_ID = ifelse(str_detect(Field_notes, '\\#'), Alt_ID, ""))
```

```
    Field_notes  Alt_ID
1 JMs # 04J0342 04J0342
2 JMs # 04J0343 04J0343
3 JMs # 04J0344 04J0344
4    broken leg        
5          54.2        
6 JMs # 04J0345 04J0345
```

Comment: I edited the comment to add an # in one of the rows where I don't want the information moved to Alt_ID. The idea is I probably can't rely on the # as an indicator, but instead probably have to rely on row names/numbers.

Comment: @Jacob could you add a row to your question where `#` is contained but you do not need the information? Or rather, what is the pattern you are looking for?

Comment: Can you please explain `'\\b\\w+$'`?

Comment: @onyambu I'm trying to avoid looking for patterns to do this because I have tens of thousands of rows in the actual dataframe with all sorts of information. I'd rather be able to subset information by specifying row numbers and then identifying within those rows the pattern needed to extract the information I want. Does that make sense?

Comment: Exelently explained here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874234/difference-between-w-and-b-regular-expression-meta-characters> by @Ωmega

Comment: @Jacob then since there is no pattern, there is no way to extract the information. I see the pattern `JMs #` but since that is not the pattern, you cannot be able to extract the information.

Comment: @onyambu Surely there must be a way to just extract partial strings from specific rows. No?

Comment: @Jacob Sure but the partial string should have a pattern or any other attribute so that we can identify! :-)

Comment: @Jacob Not unless you know the pattern or what you want from the string. ie do you know the position? do you know the pattern? or do you know the string?eg If I tell you i want a `2` from `abcd2` and then I want a `c` from `dcef` and I ask you to get the `a` from `dfga`, there is no automation to get the `a` since no enough information

Comment: @TarJae I agree. In this case, I first want to specify rows 1,2,3, and 6 and then subset the string after the pattern "JMs # ". The problem is, the pattern will change for each set of rows I specify. The part I'm struggling with is how to specify rows first.

Comment: Best would be to give a light full example. I am sure that specifying rows will not be the problem.

Comment: @TarJae Is it possible you could show how to specify rows and combine that with the pattern "JMs # " so I can see how it is done?

Comment: If you know which rows you want then it is no problem, but I think that you don't know the row numbers. You can do with `arrange(desc(Field_notes))` a grouping of patterns visually. I have edited the answer with a new approach! Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(
  Alt_ID = NA_character_,
  Field_notes = c("JMs # 04J0342", "JMs # 04J0343", "JMs # 04J0344",
                   "# broken leg", "54.2", "JMs # 04J0345")
)

id_pattern <- "(?<=JMs # )\\w+"

df %>%
  mutate(
    Alt_ID = str_extract(Field_notes, id_pattern)
  )
#    Alt_ID   Field_notes
# 1 04J0342 JMs # 04J0342
# 2 04J0343 JMs # 04J0343
# 3 04J0344 JMs # 04J0344
# 4    <NA>  # broken leg
# 5    <NA>          54.2
# 6 04J0345 JMs # 04J0345

# Or equivalently:
df$Alt_ID <- str_extract(df$Field_notes, id_pattern)
df
#    Alt_ID   Field_notes
# 1 04J0342 JMs # 04J0342
# 2 04J0343 JMs # 04J0343
# 3 04J0344 JMs # 04J0344
# 4    <NA>  # broken leg
# 5    <NA>          54.2
# 6 04J0345 JMs # 04J0345
```

The regex `"(?<=JMs # )\\w+"` is interpreted as find the substring `"JMs #`  and match the alphanumeric substring that follows.

Comment: See comment below, but this is also an acceptable answer. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, using the regex `JMs\\s#\\s(\\w+)$` and picking out the capturing group:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, Alt_ID = stringr::str_match(field_notes, "JMs\\s#\\s(\\w+)$")[, 2])
```

Output:

```
   Alt_ID   field_notes
1 04J0342 JMs # 04J0342
2    <NA>  # broken leg
3 04J0334 JMs # 04J0334
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far in that it only works on the rows I listed in the example, so kudos and thank you. Instead of specifying rows to subset, I could just update the pattern listed here which is a good option. However, I'd still like to know how to specify rows.

Comment: I guess my remaining question is, if I keep updating the pattern recognition section of code to subset other rows, will the NAs overwrite the updates of previous pattern matches?

Comment: Do you already know which rows you want to subset / is there a clear way of identifying which ones? Or alternatively, if the pattern varies a bit, do you have a set of formats you'd want to look for rather than just the 'JMs # 1111' one that you've got in your example? I think potentially updating your example to reflect how these patterns can vary could be helpful